# Delete from database doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, mysql, header, delete-row

So i have Many-to-many extra table and i want to delete a row from the extra table .

```
CREATE TABLE `person_cars` (
  `person_cars_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `person_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `car_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`person_cars_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This PHP doesn't work

```
    if(isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['person_cars_id'])) {

    $person_id = $_GET['id'];
    $person_cars_id = $_GET['person_cars_id'];
    $person->deleteCarOfPerson($person_cars_id);
    header('location:join.php?id=' + $person_id);
}
```

SQL

```
    public function deleteCarOfPerson($person_cars_id) {
    $sql = ("DELETE FROM person_cars
            WHERE person_cars_id = '{$person_cars_id}'");
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->mysql_database->getConnection());
    return $result; 
}
```

Now delete is working but not `header('location:join.php?id=' + $person_id);`

```
    if(isset($_GET['person_cars_id'])) {

    $person_id = $_GET['id'];
    $person_cars_id = $_GET['person_cars_id'];
    $person->deleteCarOfPerson($person_cars_id);
    header('location:join.php?id=' + $person_id);
}
```

Comment: `header('Location: join.php?id='.$person_id);`

Answer (score 0):

Your re-direct isn't working as you're mixing PHP with Javascript.

Change

```
header('location:join.php?id=' + $person_id);
```

to

```
header('Location: join.php?id='.$person_id);
```

`+` is used in Javascript to add something.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked this but i've got this error * You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1* and redirect still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever use header function you should use exit also after header redirection.

header("lOCATION:JOIN.PHP");
EXIT;